# 3CF 3-conjunctive form satisfiability

Tags: logic, satisfiability, 3-sat, normal-forms

I am self studying discrete math and I am going through MIT Mathematics for CS lecture notes but they do not have solutions available. I got stuck at [Problem 3.14](http://www.scribd.com/doc/101941032/3cf) (pages 64-65 of [this document](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.042/spring12/part1.pdf)). The problem is about the construction, given an arbitrary propositional formula $F$, of a proposition $C(F)$ such that:

- $C(F)$ is in 3-conjunctive form (3CF), i.e. it is a conjunction of disjunctions of at most literals (a literal is a variable or a negation of a variable);
- $C(F)$ has at most 24 times as many occurrences of variables as $F$;
- $C(F)$ is satisfiable iff $F$ is.

The idea is to introduce a new variable for each operator that occurs in $F$. For example, given
$$ F_1 = ((P \oplus Q) \oplus R) \vee (\neg P \wedge S)) $$
assign $X_1, X_2, O, A$ to the 4 operators in $F_1$, and define four *constraining formulas*:
$$ \begin{align*}
 C_1^1 &= X_1 \Leftrightarrow (P \oplus Q) \\
 C_1^2 &= X_2 \Leftrightarrow (X_1 \oplus R) \\
 C_1^3 &= A \Leftrightarrow (\neg P \wedge S) \\
 C_1^4 &= O \Leftrightarrow (X_2 \oplus A) \\
\end{align*} $$
and $C_1 = C_1^1 \wedge C_1^2 \wedge C_1^3 \wedge C_1^4 \wedge O$.

The questions are:

1. Why is $C_1$ satisfiable iff $F_1$ is satisfiable?
2. Why is each constraining formula equivalent to a 3CF formula with at most 24 occurrences of variables?
3. Generalize from the example to construct $C(F)$ for an arbitrary formula $F$.

For question 1, I don't see why $X_1$ is satisfiable.

I think question 2 is wrong, beacuse you can form a 3CF formula with at most 24 occurrences of variables, only if you have a 3-conjunctive **normal** form but here the author only says 3 conjunctive form.

(For 3CNF, 8 different triple terms can be formed using 3 variables with a total of 24 variables, For 3CF, 26 different single,double and triple terms can be formed with a total of ? variables.)

No idea about question 3.

Comment: I've edited the problem statement into your question. Please review to check that I haven't made any mistake. In the future, please include all the necessary information in your question.

Comment: Please link to the original source of the questions.

Comment: How is 3CF defined (I take it it's not 3CNF)? Note that 2 is not true for (3)CNF if you allow e.g. $\iff$ as operator. Afaik, such statements are restricted to definitions of "propositional formula" which use only a small complete operator set such as $\{\lnot, \lor, \land\}$ or $\{\lnot, \to\}$. Do you have a similar restriction? (Should it not be $O \iff (X_2 \lor A)$?)

Comment: 3CF is conjunction of OR-Clauses. Each OR clause can have at most 3 variables. Each OR clause can only use 'logical or' operator and can use variables or their negations.

Comment: @levi: That would be 3CNF, then. What is constructed is clearly not CNF, therefore my question. I guess you are allowed to use arbitrary operators in the clauses?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I assume that $C_1^4 \equiv O \iff (X_2 \lor A)$ in accordance to $F_1$. Second, note that 3CF as defined in the exercise is equivalent to [3CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-CNF). In the following, I will denote with $\phi_X$ the subformula of the given formula $F$ which has been assigned new variable $X$ by the construction. For example, $\phi_A=(\lnot P \land S)$ and $\phi_O = F_1$.
$\renewcommand{\models}{\mathop{|\!\!\!=}}\newcommand{\rmodels}{\mathop{=\!\!\!|}} \newcommand{\semeq}{\models\!\rmodels}$

### Satisfaction equivalence

> I don't see why $X_1$ is satisfiable

$X_1$ is a single variable and thus trivially satisfiable (by setting it to $1$). The $C_1^i$ essentially take apart $F_1$ operator by operator, introducing new variables that have to evaluate to the same truth values as their respective subformulae. Using $\{O\}$ as clause of $C_1$ guarantees the statement, essentially (as "$O \semeq F_1$", given $C_1$).

#### Proof

Assume $F_1$ is satisfiable and let $\psi$ be a satisfying valuation of the variables. Construct $\psi'$ by extending $\psi$ with $\psi'(X) = \psi(\phi_{X})$ for $X \in \{X_1,X_2,A,O\}$. As a consequence, $\psi'$ satisfies all $C_i^1$. Because $\psi(F_1)=1$ by assumption, we have chosen $\psi'(O)=1$. Therefore, $\psi'(C_1)=1$.

Conversely, assume $C_1$ is satisfiable and let $\psi$ a satisfying valuation. Clearly, $\psi(O)=1$ and $\psi(C_1^4)=1$. Therefore, $\psi(\psi_O)=1$. Because $\psi_O=F_1$, we are done -- $\psi$ satisfies $F_1$. In order to be rigorous, we would have to iterate this argument top-down, following the structure of $F_1$, to unfold $X_2$ and then $X_1$ (in the general case, we would need a structural induction here).

### Size restriction

The constraining formulae all have the same form and are small (three literals, two operators). You can transform those into equivalent 3CF formulae *locally*, i.e. ignoring the others. This conversion always yields formulae with at most 24 literals, that is at most 8 clauses. This can be shown by dull calculation.

#### Details

The general form of a contraining formula is $A \iff (A \circ B)$ for $\circ$ some logical operator. Let us transform it into 3CF using [laws and rules of boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic#Laws).

$\qquad \begin{align}
  C^i &\equiv X \iff (A \circ B) \\
      &\semeq\ [X \land (A \circ B)] \lor [\lnot X \land \lnot(A \circ B)] \\
      &\semeq\ [\lnot X \lor (A \circ B)] \land [ X \lor \lnot(A \circ B)] 
\end{align}$

Now, for $\circ = \land$, we use both distributive and associative law resp. De Morgan's rule:

$\qquad \begin{align}
  C^i &\semeq\ [\lnot X \lor (A \land B)] \land [ X \lor \lnot(A \land B)] \\
      &\semeq\ [\lnot X \lor A] \land [\lnot X \lor B] \land [ X \lor \lnot A \lor \lnot B]
\end{align}$

This has three clauses (after padding with redundant literals, nine literals). For $\circ \in \{\lor, \to\}$¹ this works exactly the same way. You can proceed similarly for other choices of $\circ$, such as $\oplus$ or $\iff$, depending on which operators are allowed in your setting.

### Generalisation

This is just a matter of writing down what the example does in general terms. Let $F$ an arbitrary propositional formula, w.l.o.g. without "negation chains"². Now do the following.

$\quad$ Let $i=0$.
$\quad$ Until $F$ is a literal, do
$\qquad$  Increase $i$ by one.
$\qquad$  Pick a subformula of $F$ of the form $L_1 \circ L_2 = \phi$ with $L_1,L_2$ literals.
$\qquad$  Let $C^i \equiv X_i \iff (L_1 \circ L_2)$.
$\qquad$  Replace $\phi$ with $X_i$ in $F$.
$\quad$ For all $j=1,\dots,i$, convert $C^j$ into 3CF by finite case distinction.
$\quad$ Return $[F \lor F \lor F] \land \bigwedge_{j=1}^{i} C^j$.

Note that $F = X_i$ after the loop. For intuition and implementation purposes, think of a formula as a tree: operators are inner nodes, leaves are literals. Above algorithm iteratively contracts subtrees of height two into leaves, collecting the $C^j$ as "mapping" from new variable to the removed subtree along the way.

---

1. Remember $A \to B \semeq \lnot A \lor B$.
2. We can always use $\lnot \lnot A \semeq A$.